# "unexpected unindent" for correct indentation?

Tags: python, indentation

trying to make an autoclicker in python, not going so well. once i think i finally got it right it says `unexpected unindent.`

indentation seems correct though? i don't see whats wrong.

also, i would love if you guys give me recommendations on how to make my code better, as i am a beginner in this :/

```
import pyautogui, mouse, keyboard, sys

delay=0.01

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            sys.exit()
def left_mouse():
    while True:
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.delay=delay
mouse.on_click(left_mouse)
```

in IDLE the red error indicator shows on the right side of sys.exit()
doesn't seem to be a problem there though?

Answer (score 3):

In python a `try:` block will need to have at least one `except:` or `finally:` block following it. If you want to ignore the possible exceptions thrown in your try block you can do:

```
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            sys.exit()
    except:
        pass
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `try`:

```
delay=0.01

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        sys.exit()
def left_mouse():
    while True:
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.delay=delay
mouse.on_click(left_mouse)
```

Comment: it turns out that removing "try:" worked, all i had to do was fix the indentation.

i think that might have messed up my loop though

Comment: probably going to delete this script anyways since it doesn't even work :P